# How can i restrict a user to just see his own journal entries in Odoo online

Tags: odoo

I really need to restrict a user in Odoo online so he can just see his own journal entries, and also make edits to just his own entries. I have seen tons of solutions but those solutions are just for the Odoo open source where they can modify the source code. I want a solution where I can apply it in Odoo online

Comment: Check this [link](https://odootricks.tips/about/building-blocks/security/record-rules/) to access this view, you will need to open debug mode. In this blog, they explained a little about how to add rules to models from the odoo front ends. Note that when you are restricting via rule, check if there is a rule that's giving the rights that you are trying to restrict and change that one accordingly also, don't do it in production first use demo or runbot make sure you have tested correctly and have database backup of your DB before changing in production.

Comment: for edit, you have to change the access of the group you will assign this rule to 
when he is only able to see his record the giving them write access will only allow them to write those record

Answer (score -1):

yes you can do this with company restriction, this will solve your problem.
I mean this :

> **for each record that create by any user from company 'a' can't see or edit by other users from other companies**

try like this :

1 - add these lines to all your models

```
class Help(models.Model):
    _name = 'your_model'
    _check_company_auto = True

    company_id = fields.Many2one('res.company', required=True, default=lambda self: self.env.company)
```

2 - add these lines in security rules file :

```
<record model="ir.rule" id="record_restricted_company_rule">
    <field name="name">Restricted Record: multi-company</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_your_model"/>
    <field name="global" eval="True"/>
    <field name="domain_force">
        [('company_id', 'in', company_ids)]
    </field>
</record>
```